# Unable to commit after performing svn switch

Tags: svn

I have an issue using the svn switch command where I have committed to the trunk and then want to switch to a branch and commit that revision to that branch. I'm sure I have done this before, dead easy...just do a `svn switch [BRANCHURL]` and then `svn commit -m 'COMMIT MESSAGE IN HERE'`. This does not seem to work.

When I done the switch it showed the changes as "Updated" then when I went to commit there was nothing to commit. Any ideas what i've done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, to clarify, what you've done is

1. modify a file
2. commit to trunk
3. switch to the branch

Note that after 2 you will have a clean copy of the trunk with no uncommitted changes, and so when you switch to the branch it will revert to a clean copy of the branch.

You now need to do

```
svn merge -c [the commit rev] [TRUNKURL]
```

to merge the change into your branch working copy so you can commit it there too.

Comment: Am I not able to commit the change to the branch _without_ checking the branch out? My normal procedure is to do a "merge -c" for an individual revision, but I have many branches to work with and i'd prefer not to have to check them out all the time. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused: didn't you say you `svn switch` ed your trunk checkout into a branch checkout? Yes unfortunatley you will need a checkout of any branch you want to commit into - so you can solve any merge conflicts, run your unit tests, etc. before committing -  although you can switch checkouts between branches if you want.